Repeated TUXEDO Control Center Service Error: Cannot Access /run/user/1000/Xauthority
I'm experiencing an issue with the TUXEDO Control Center Service (tccd) on my system. The service is running, but it keeps logging the following errors every 5 seconds about not being able to access /run/user/1000/Xauthority:
Jun 15 10:48:20 m tccd[1971]: ls: cannot access '/run/user/1000/Xauthority': No such file or directory
Jun 15 10:48:25 m tccd[1971]: ls: cannot access '/run/user/1000/Xauthority': No such file or directory
Jun 15 10:48:25 m tccd[1971]: Failed executing onWork() => Error: Command failed: ls -l /run/user/1000/Xauthority

If tried checking systemctl status tccd but the service seems to be running fine:
 tccd.service - TUXEDO Control Center Service
     Loaded: loaded (/etc/systemd/system/tccd.service; enabled; vendor preset: enabled)
     Active: active (running) since Fri 2024-06-14 13:44:38 CEST; 21h ago
   Main PID: 1971 (tccd)
      Tasks: 6 (limit: 37541)
     Memory: 103.2M
     CGroup: /system.slice/tccd.service
             └─1971 /opt/tuxedo-control-center/resources/dist/tuxedo-control-center/data/service/tccd --start

Question: There indeed is no 'Xauthority' file located at '/run/user/1000/'. Why might this file be missing? Should I recreate this file? If it is not required, is there a way to configure tccd to stop looking for this file if it's not needed? Could this issue affect my system in other ways?
Any help or suggestions would be appreciated.

multiple things: there's no reason that file should exist if you're not running X; and many modern linux distros use wayland instead of X. Then, not a good look to see ls appear in logs; that's really not a tool you would expect to be used in daemons (it's aiming at producing output for human readers, not computer programs; whatever you do with it in a script is probably better done with [[ … ]], globs, stat or similar tools) . So, seeing that research tells me this is a hardware vendor tool: maybe write them? They might have an updated version.

Note that the Xauthority files live in a different place on my machine, as well. You cannot recreate it – that makes no sense, it needs to be the one used by the party actually in charge of allowing things related to X – so I'd go with "this is a software bug with Tuxedo's software"

The Xauthority file contains the "password" for graphical apps to access your X11 display server (Xorg, Xwayland). The location that your service is looking for is not quite standard, although it's a reasonable guess (indeed there have been attempts to make this path standard; I'm sure I have seen a display manager – perhaps it was LightDM? – which used this path, and my own ~/bin/startx uses it as well).
If you are running X11, then the default location of the file is ~/.Xauthority, but your display manager (e.g. GDM) may choose a different location and set $XAUTHORITY accordingly. So if the file exists:
ls -l ~/.Xauthority
ls -l "$XAUTHORITY"

and contains reasonable-looking data:
xauth list

then you can try symlinking it to where the daemon wants it:
ln -s ~/.Xauthority "$XDG_RUNTIME_DIR/Xauthority"

If you are running Wayland and your compositor (WM) starts Xwayland, then it most likely will also set $XAUTHORITY for you. Pure Wayland doesn't use Xauth, but pure-Wayland desktops are rare.
If you aren't running X11 (neither stand-alone nor Xwayland), then most likely you won't have an Xauthority file, since there's nothing it would control access to. In that case – or if you just don't want to give the daemon any access to your X display – you can manually create a dummy Xauthority file using xauth, like this:
xauth -f <path> add :0 MIT-MAGIC-COOKIE-1 $(mcookie)

in which mcookie (or uuidgen|sed s/-//g) generates a random hex key which is then inserted as the auth key for the :0 display.
To be honest, I'm really suspicious of any system daemons trying to access X11. It might be legitimate, but it is really bad design to do so. (Normally you would have a stand-alone GUI 'applet' that reaches to the service instead, such as nm-applet talking to NetworkManager.) Even more suspicious is that the service tries to use ls -l in any way at all – literally every programming language (even shell!) has more direct ways to check whether a file exists.
